# What is the shortcut for inspecting elements in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I read the documentation about Firefox's [page inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector#Selecting-Elements). I didn't find any shortcut for inspecting an element directly without clicking the button 'choose element with mouse'. The documentation for opening the inspector itself even looks to be wrong.

You open it with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> on OSX rather than <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> as described in the documentation.

Using Firefox v24

Comment: Strongly recommend installing the `firebug` add on. http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Not sure it will help, but if right click on the element you want to inspect and hit "Q" it will directly open inspector with that element selected.

Comment: @Der Flatulator, firebug and firefox own inspector seem very similar to be honest.

Comment: Now firebug is discontinued and merged into Firefox inspector, this is very relevant now

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18993301/712334) for the shortcut which, after many years of Chrome dev, I find a refreshing and intuitive workflow adjustment—not to mention more accessible.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems that <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd> always open the inspector in "choose element with mouse" mode.  [Linux, FF 26.0.  Also works in Chrome.]

It's not exactly the same flow as context menu -> inspect element but I find it more useful.  The hover tooltip sometimes gives me all the info I need.  And it's more reliable — just opening the context menu generates a mouse event while <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd> doesn't.  E.g. with CodeMirror which [plays games with invisible elements](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/browser-input-reading.html), using context menu usually lands me in the hidden textarea or fake cursor, while "choose with mouse" mode reliably gives me the styled editor content I wanted to inspect.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04 FF 46.0.1 that shortcut doesn't work. Maybe something has changed? I can test on my Unity session, I can confirm on gnome-session it doesn't

Answer (score 16):

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: How come this is the only correct answer for Mac? Even the ff docs say it is cmd+shift+c, but it isn't. +1 internet to you sir

Comment: cmd+option+C worked for me on Firefox 49 on mac os Yosemite.

Comment: Also on Mac, if you are using [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/), make sure to disable the Cmd+Option+C shortcut for centering the current window, as it will interfere with the Inspect element shortcut.

Comment: I was stuck with Spectacle, BRAVO!

Answer (score 8):

Ctr + Shift + C and function F12 button is default inspect element button for every browser.
So if firebug isn't installed in your firefox then F12 button is the shortest shortcut for your goal.

Comment: As of Firefox 55, Ctrl-Shift-Q closes the browser :/

Comment: Thank you, @Moira: I thought that Spondon Ahsan's answer was trolling.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the way you do it in Mac OS, but on windows, if you select the element by pressing tab until you reach it, if you press the context menu key and then <kbd>Q</kbd>, you open the inspector on that specific element, like it happens when you right click on it.

I believe the context menu key is not a mac thing, but it seems that there are people that worked around to do it. See this question: [How do I open the context menu from a Mac keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/how-do-i-open-the-context-menu-from-a-mac-keyboard).

Comment: This is easier to use, however it's annoying that the margin indicators only lasted a second before they disappears

Comment: I wish there was a way to use Q on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac (I'm using Yosemite though), it's <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) and Firefox (version 72.0.2) it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> , or hotkey <kbd>F12</kbd>.